# In data table, Compare rows and make calculations without loop in R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, datatable

I have a data table with columns `id`, `starts`, `ends`, `same_person`

`same_person` is used to check whether the row has the same id as the one before.

```
library(data.table)
id = c(1,1,2,2)
starts = c(0,5,0,9)
ends = c(5,10,9,20)
same_person = c(0,0,0,0)
df <- data.table(id, starts, ends, same_person)

df
      id starts ends same_person
# 1:  1      0    5           0
# 2:  1      5   10           0
# 3:  2      0    9           0
# 4:  2      9   20           0
```

The expected outputs are:

1.Compare the `id` of two consecutive rows and if they are the same, replace `same_person` as 1.
2.For the same person, make the `starts` equal to the first row.

I used 2 for loops to realize them.

First, I check `id` of one row with the row before, and if same, replacing `same_person` as 1.

```
for (i in 2:nrow(df)){
    if(df$id[i] == df$id[i-1]){
        df$same_person[i] <- 1   
    }
   }

df
      id starts ends same_person
# 1:  1      0    5           0
# 2:  1      5   10           1
# 3:  2      0    9           0
# 4:  2      9   20           1
```

Based on the result before, I change `starts` if they are the same person.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
    if(df$same_person[i] == 1){
     df$starts[i] <- df$starts[i-1]    
    }
 }


df
      id starts ends same_person
# 1:  1      0    5           0
# 2:  1      0   10           1
# 3:  2      0    9           0
# 4:  2      0   20           1
```

Since this data table is an simplified version, it does not take long time. But in my real work, it takes a lot.

I am wondering wether I can realize the two steps without using a loop.

Comment: What is the expected output

Comment: The expected outputs are: 1. Compare the `id` of two consecutive rows and if they are the same, replace `same_person` as 1.    2. For the same person, make the start time equal to the first row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line finds the duplicates and then next line replace the duplicates of the `starts` from the first value that appear in the `data.frame`.

```
   df$same_person <- 1 * duplicated(df$id)
    df$starts[which(df$same_person == 1)] <- 
      df$starts[which(df$same_person == 1) - 1]
```

Comment: Thanks. What if same `id` appears more than twice and I only need the `same_person` in the last row of each id to become 1.

Comment: And what if I want to compare two columns. For example, there are no `id` column, and if the `starts` at second row equals to the `ends` time in the first row. They are the `same_person`.

Comment: If you have the `id`s sorted, then you'll get `1` in each of the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your comments, it seems you want to do a lot of things. In that case, it may be better to write a loop.

First find what are the unique id's and then handle them. Following puts `1` is only the last row of `same_person` with same `id`.

```
unique_ids <- unique(df$id)
for (uid in unique_ids) {
  n_rows <- which(df$id == uid)
  if (length(n_rows) > 2)
  df$same_person[max(n_rows)] <- 1
}
```